# how do I get a the colour of the pixel I just touched

Tags: android

I have two images and one goes on top of the other. The bottom one is a floor plan and the above image is the same image but all of the rooms have been coloured in with different colours. The top image is then made invisible. I want to get the colour of the area that was touched so that I know where users want to go.

I don't know if this can be done and if you know of another way to make an area clickable I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the actual image, you can just compute the image coordinates of the pixel that was clicked and read the pixel from the image data, something like [`Bitmap.getPixel(int,int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel%28int,%20int%29).

An alternative which wouldn't require you to store two images is something akin to an [image map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map), where you'd be storing the polygons for the different regions.

Answer (score 2):

Get pixel from view like this 
 int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

Now you can get each value of RGB like:
int redValue = Color.red(pixel);